# Passing values to PowerShell.Exiting event actions

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell scripting so maybe I've just missed something. The script log changes in file system to file and also starting & finishing script.

```
$logPath = "C:\temp\watcher.log"
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -MessageData $logPath -Action {
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated.ToString("s")
    Out-File -FilePath $Event.MessageData -Append -InputObject "$timeStamp    Finished"
}
```

Passing values in IO.FileSystemWatcher events works great. But value in PowerShell.Exiting event doesn't pass. What's wrong?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?  There were some issues in V2 with the runspace not being valid when this event executed. That was fixed in V3 but you only get 5 seconds to finish your Action scriptblock.

Comment: PSVersion=4.0, WSManStackVersion=3.0, SerializationVersion=1.1.0.1, CLRVersion=4.0.30319.34014, BuildVersion=6.3.9600.16394, PSCompatibleVersions={1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}, 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion=2.2

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but may serve as a work-around. This is how I do this:

```
$historyPath = Join-Path (split-path $profile) "history-$(Get-Date -f o).clixml"
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    Get-History | Export-Clixml $historyPath
}.GetNewClosure()
```

Using `GetNewClosure()` the scriptblock can capture the value of the external `$historyPath` variable